# Given a PMID, how can I get the list of PMIDs of papers citing it?

Tags: data-request, api, research, pubmed

Given a PMID (=[PubMed identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubMed#PubMed_identifier)), how can I get the list of PMIDs of papers citing it? Dataset, API, or any other solution is fine.